# PayPal API with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal

Hi I want to integrate Paypal API in my Zend FW 1 application.

my code is

```
$this->setHeaders(
            array(
                'Authorization' => '<REMOVED>',
                'content-type' => 'application/json',
            )
        );
        $this->setMethod('POST');
        $this->setParameterGet('payer_id', $company_id);
        $this->setParameterGet('number', $cc_number);
        $this->setParameterGet('type', $type);
        $this->setParameterGet('exp_month', $exp_month);
        $this->setParameterGet('exp_year', $exp_year);
        $this->setParameterGet('payer_id', $company_id);
        $this->setParameterGet('first_name', $first_name);
        $this->setParameterGet('last_name', $last_name);
        return $this->request();
```

Debug show this

```
       string(364) "POST /v1/vault/credit-card?number=4417119669820331&type=visa&exp_month=05&exp_year=2019&first_name=john&last_name=travolta HTTP/1.1
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Connection: close
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Zend_Http_Client
Authorization: Bearer <REMOVED>
content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
```

But when I run i get this error from PayPal
"Method Not Allowed"

Where is problem? I do POST and he said that is not allowed? Allowed method are POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS. Where i making mistakes?
I want to store credit card

Comment: You'll want to `setParameterPost()` instead of `setParameterGet()`.

Comment: Then i get "415 Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: Use this header `Accept: application/json` and send the data as json string. You'll probably need to use the `rawData` [method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html).

Comment: Yes Dennis, you are right, I send RawData and now works :) thank you aloot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal API requires strict usage of correct requests.
This includes a valid `Accept: application/json` header and valid
json content being send. **You can not set** `content-type` **without sending any content**

In this case `Zend_HTTP_Client's rawData()` should be used.